# What name best describes this style of pen-and-ink art?

Tags: style-identification

I have been working with pen and ink, doing pieces of this style for more than a decade. Many times, I have been asked for a name to describe what I do, and I'm continually left with stating that it is simply "my style."

Is there a specific style of art that would aptly describe this type of highly-detailed pen-and-ink work that uses small drawings to work together to create the whole of the piece?

[image: Abstract Flag Art by Jeffrey Blake]

Comment: Which aspect in particular are you asking about? The coloring, the small, detailed designs? The way the ink is actually laid down? Please [edit] your question with more info so we can get you some answers!

Comment: PS,  I'd personally put a more faded but diagonal watermark across the piece for your copyright. The bottom banner is easy to crop out.

Comment: "Very elaborated doodle"? (Jk - I like your work!)

Comment: Don't know of an existing term, but I'd probably coin something like "sketch fill".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I first looked at your image my reaction was "mosaic" was the root of the style, and so I did a little digging and came across the concept of "[doodle mosaic](https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=doodle%20mosaic%20drawing)" that really seems to fit.
The other reason that worked for me is that there is a Zen Doodle feel as well, the sense that the sum of the parts are creating a bigger result.

Comment: That's a good find. I'm interested in seeing more of this type of work, now.

Comment: Good find indeed. The Japanese artist in that video almost puts me to shame with his use of actual full blown cartoons (if I didn't have the hidden stuff like the names of every US president in the blue and patriotic texts in each red stripe, I'd feel more this way). Given everything, I'll take this as the best option.

Comment: Zen Doodle is a really close second as well. So double credit to you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your style also has a [**scratch art**](https://www.google.com/search?q=scratch%20art&num=30&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ) quality, where you take a light colored ground, cover it evenly with india ink, then scratch away your design.